# How do I reform my Religion?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

How do I reform my religion in Crusader kings 2? Right now I'm Pagan. I'm playing as Greater Poland in the DLC Old Gods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conquer 3 of your religion's 5 holy cities, get Religious Authority in your own religion to at least 50, make sure you have 750 piety and then hit the reform button on the religion screen.

[image]

Alternatively, if the moral authority or piety requirements are too hard you can instead control all five holy sites - this is also sufficient to reform.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this game so I'm still quite "noob" at it.

Comment: No problem. I'm actually really surprised that this question hasn't been asked before. It's not as obvious as most mechanics since it was added in the expansion